# How to fix the font that cut from the bottom?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have custom font in the app and I am using it on a `Text` as following:

```
struct CustomButton: View {

    var label: String
    var action: () -> Void

    init(_ label: String, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.label = label
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Text(label)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

and the preview is:

```
struct CustomButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomButton("Simple g Button") {
            }
            .font(.custom("NexaBold", size: 40))
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 8"))
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see the character `g` doesn't displayed well and cut from the bottom. I have verified in the font file that it is complete but the `Text` displayed it as cut from the bottom.

I have tried to add more `padding` but that doesn't fix the issue.

Please help, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, below looks like workaround, but it works, so try...

[image]

```
    Button(action: action) {
        Text(label)
            .baselineOffset(2) // << shifted baseline !
            .font(.custom("Nexa Bold", size: 40))
            .padding()
    }
```

Comment: Does not work however with e.g Ü, as its cut off at the top aswell ...

Comment: It's a workaround, not a solution. It will move the text higher. Text won't be vertically centered anymore and can cause problems at the top as @lr058 mentioned